# Flask WTF-Alchemy: SelectField with one-to-many relationship won't populate

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a one-to-many relationship between Scenario (which defines the characteristics of a project) and Module (which defines the technical characteristics of a solar panel): several projects can use the same photovoltaic module.

I have defined a few modules and I would now like to be able to pick one in the Scenario definition page.

I can pull the data from my db and can get the select field display correctly with the code below.

However, when submitting the form, I get a SQL error : `InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. [SQL: u'UPDATE scenario SET module_id=? WHERE scenario.id = ?'] [parameters: ([], 1)]`. It looks like my form submits empty lists and I don't know what to change.

I've found a few related questions on SO but none using WTF Alchemy to automatically populate the fields (which I'd like to keep).

Any help will be appreciated!

`macros.html`

```
    {% if field.type in ['ModelFieldList', 'QuerySelectField'] %}  
    <div class="control-group">
    <select name="{{field.name}}" class="form-control">
      {% for choice in field.choices %}
        <option value="{{choice.id}}">{{choice.name}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
     </select>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    ...#Other fields 
    {% endif %}
```

`models.py`

```
    class Scenario(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, 
            primary_key=True, 
            autoincrement=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(140), 
            nullable=False, 
            info={'label': 'Name'})
        module_id = db.Column(db.Integer, 
            db.ForeignKey(Module.id))

        def __repr__(self):
            return '{}'.format(self.name)

    class Module(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(140), nullable=False, 
                info={'label': 'Name'},
                 unique=False)
        scenario_list = db.relationship('Scenario', 
            backref=db.relationship('Scenario', backref='module', lazy='dynamic')

        def __repr__(self):
            return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

`forms.py`

```
    ModelForm = model_form_factory(Form)

    class ModuleForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Module

    class ScenarioForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Scenario
        module_id =  ModelFieldList(SelectField(ModuleForm, coerce=int), 
            label= 'Module')
```

`views.py`

```
    @app.route('/scenario/<int:id>/edit', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def edit_scenario(id):
        scenario = Scenario.query.get(id)
        form = ScenarioForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            form.populate_obj(scenario)
            db.session.commit()
            flash("{} successfully edited".format(scenario), "success")
            form_action = url_for('scenario', id=id)
            return redirect(form_action)
        form = ScenarioForm(obj=scenario)
        form.module_id.choices = db.session.query(Module.id, Module.name)

        form_title = "Scenario"
        form_action = url_for('edit_scenario', id=id)
        return  render_template('form.html', 
            form = form, 
            form_title = form_title,
            form_action = form_action)
```

**EDIT**
Following @dirn answer, I've made some changes: it now works except that I've lost the labels for my module field. Almost there!

`forms.py`

```
    class ScenarioForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
        model = Scenario
      module_id =  SelectField(ModuleForm, choices = [(x.id, x.name) for x in db.session.query(Module).all()], coerce=int)
```

`macros.html`

```
  {% if field.type in ['ModelFieldList', 'QuerySelectField', 'SelectField'] %}
  <div class="control-group">
    <select name="{{field.name}}" class="form-control">
      {% for id, name in field.choices %}
        <option value="{{id}}">{{name}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>
  {% else %}
  ...
  {% endif %}
```

**EDIT** 
I had copy-pasted the syntax from a tutorial without understanding it and I was initializing the `SelectField()` function with `ModuleForm`. Turns out it's useless and I need instead to put the label there.

`forms.py`

```
    class ScenarioForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
        model = Scenario
      module_id =  SelectField('Module', choices = [(x.id, x.name) for x in db.session.query(Module).all()], coerce=int)
```

Comment: Your first problem is that a `Scenario` can only have one `Module`, but `ScenarioForm.module_id` supports a list (through `ModelFieldList`). It should be a single `SelectField`.

Comment: Thanks a lot dirn. I'm almost there. I just can't figure out where to define the label of this select field. When I print the labels of my form, I get the correct `<label for="size">Size</label>` markdown for the regular fields, while the select field has `<label for="module_id"><class 'app.forms.ModuleForm'></label>` and there is no label on the HTML page... Where should I change this property?

Comment: `module_id =  SelectField('Module', choices = [(x.id, x.name) for x in db.session.query(Module).all()], coerce=int)` does the trick... Thanks again.